# Не получается вытянуть данные из HTML

Tags: c#, html

```
    private Models getAttributes(HtmlDocument htmlCode)
    {
        List<HtmlNode> tr = htmlCode.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[contains(@class,'attributes')]").Elements("tr").ToList();

        var result = new Models();

        foreach (HtmlNode node in tr)
        {
            List<HtmlNode> s = node.SelectNodes("th|td").ToList();

            if (s[0].InnerText.Contains("Артикул:"))
                result.Arktikul = Convert.ToInt16(Regex.Match(s[1].InnerText, @"[0-9][0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]*)?"));
            if (s[0].InnerText.Contains("Остаток на складе:"))
                result.Warehouse = s[1].InnerText.Trim();
            if (s[0].InnerText.Contains("Страна-производитель:"))
                result.CountryCreator = s[1].InnerText.Trim();
        }

        return result;
    }


public class Models

{
    [Display(Name = "Арктикул:")]
    public int Arktikul { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Остаток на складе:")]
    public string Warehouse { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Страна-производитель:")]
    public string CountryCreator { get; set; }
}
```

При выполнении находит только Арктикул и foreach завершается, return тоже не отрабатывает, ошибку не выдает, не получается разложить в модель, уже всю голову сломал, нужна помощь!

Comment: Пример страницы, которую вы пытаетесь распарсить - в студию. Код выглядит нормально. Разве что `Convert.ToInt16` смущает (почему не Int32?!)

Comment: А вообще - отладчик в помощь. Там можно сразу увидеть, какие именно строки находятся, чему равны `InnerText` и т.п. Умение пользоваться отладчиком - очень важное.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, вы навели меня на мысль, проблема была в result.Arktikul = Convert.ToInt16(Regex.Match(s[1].InnerText, @"[0-9][0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]*)?").Value); я забыл получать значение и странно что при вызове Convert.ToInt16 не происходила остановка программы из за ошибки.

Comment: Дмитрий, лучше напишите тогда на свой вопрос ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
result.Arktikul = Convert.ToInt16(Regex.Match(s[1].InnerText, @"[0-9][0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]*)?").Value))
```

забыл получать значение